# Flash Photo Album Creator

Tags: php, mysql, flash

It's been a long time since I did anything in flash, and today, I just received an assignment to create a photo album creator (aka PAC) with a PHP/Mysql backend.  It would be great if anyone can recommend off the shelf modules I can incorporate into my project.  Any additional advice would be helpful.   Here are the requirements for the PAC:

a) user can upload N number of photos into the PAC, which means I'll need a good file manager that let's people add, delete, move and rename files on the server

b) user can create M number of pages in a photo album and then assign any combination of images to a particular page

c) user can resize images on any page

d) user can crop any image on any page

e) user can save the album and edit it at a later time

Each of the items above could take at least  a week to build from scratch.  Is there anything out there that can expedite my development time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks more like a superuser.com question.

I'm no PHP expert but here are some thoughts:

- a) [PHPfm](http://phpfm.sourceforge.net/#screenshots) or [FileThingie](http://www.solitude.dk/filethingie/tour) might
  do it for files.
- b) It's up to you how you organize/design
  your table/database structure to
  accomodate collections/albums/etc.
- c,d) - [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) or [GD
  library](http://www.libgd.org/Main_Page) can easily handle crops
  and resize, and even more.
- e) - see b)

[image: slideshow pro logo]

If it's a commercial project and time **is** a constraint consider solutions like [SlideShowPro](http://slideshowpro.net/).

It has been around for a few good years, has a nice design, good support, in short it's an **affordable and professional product**.

If you don't consider buying this, analyze it, break it down, see what works well and how and most importantly how you can improve this.